# Javascript document.body.style.backgroundImage causes php mysql queries to run?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, background-image

So it took me quite a bit of time to figure out what was happening and how my database was updating its self randomly but I discovered its directly related to using:
`document.body.style.backgroundImage` in Javascript.

Does anyone know how to prevent this from running my queries again or how `document.body.style.backgroundImage` works? Alternatives? I can't afford to have queries running constantly for Javascript to change the background.

**Specifics**

I am running website that at the beginning of the page load PHP gets the `time()` and stores it in a database using `mysql_query()` statement. 
I've recently implemented on my website a Javascript loop that runs every so often and changes the background using this code in a function: `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";`

I noticed that when this runs and the background is changed, somehow the queries get run again on my website and it updates my database again changing the time.
I've isolated the cause by commenting out the javascript background change statement letting the rest of the loop run like normal. After that, it no longer updates. As soon as I un-comment that line and the problem occurs again.

Comment: Can you please share some code? It would really help to answer your question.

Comment: Sounds like a page refresh is occurring.

Comment: Check your routing, it looks like this background http request is processed as your normal request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you set the background image to `url('')`, you're effectively telling the browser to make an HTTP request for the page you're currently on. The empty string '' is considered a relative URL. (It's the same thing that happens when you omit the `action` of a form, or set it to '' - the form will submit to the current page.)

To get around this, try `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "";` instead of `url('')`.

Comment: No problem - Please try accepting some answers, it will make people more likely to want to help you :)

Comment: Do you know the correct syntax for `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "";` 
If I do it like this it wont work.
`document.body.style.backgroundImage = "images/image.jpg";` I've tried with a / and a ./ and ../ just to be sure =/

Comment: That is the correct syntax... If it is empty, use `""`. If it's not empty, use `url(/whatever/)`.

Comment: hmm I don't know why it wont get the image then :(

Comment: It works =D It's no longer updating the DB. So the single quotes in `url('')` makes it do an HTTP request while `url()` does a relative request.   Thank you again!

Comment: Well, not quite...  `backgroundImage = ""` doesn't make an HTTP request. `backgroundImage = "url('')"` makes an HTTP request to a relative path.